# laravel route post route with one forward slash assume it to be a get route

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes, postman

I have created a **room** resource in Laravel 5.3
if I run **http://testlara.dev/api/room**  with POST Method  it runs the store method of the RoomController (as intended)

but when I accidently put one forward slash 
like **http://testlara.dev/api/room/**  although the method is POST  but it runs the index method of the RoomController ( GET Method is assumed)

can anyone explain why is that so ?

I did the testing using POSTMAN

Answer (score 1):

By requesting `http://testlara.dev/api/room/` you are assuming that there is an id after the slash like this : `api/room/{id}` and it is an empty value

[Route List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFrIb.png)

Comment: but if the id is not there  then why does it route back to index method  and not generating the error or exception

Comment: try to run `php artisan route:list`